# Ionic/Cordova Identify platform during config stage

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Is there a way for me identify current platform(iOS or Android) during config stage?

I want to do

```
var core = angular.module("app.core");
```

and then in config...

```
core.config(.....);
```

i need to have a platform in core.config to get different translation files and few other setting

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
core.config(function() {
    var isIOS = ionic.Platform.isIOS();
    var isAndroid = ionic.Platform.isAndroid();
});
```